# How to print negative numbers within a parenthesis with spreadtab in LaTex

Tags: format, latex, markdown, accounting, xelatex

I am trying to produce financial statements with latex. An important convention of financial statements is that negative numbers are not presented with a negative sign, rather wrapped in parentheses, like this:
`-100 -> (100)`

The minimum necessary recreation of my issue is as follows:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{spreadtab}
\usepackage{numprint}
\npthousandsep{,}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\STautoround{0}
\begin{spreadtab}{{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XN{7}{0}N{7}{0}}}
@\multicolumn{3}{c}{\uppercase{Municipal Government}}\\
@\multicolumn{3}{c}{Statement of Net Position}\\
@\multicolumn{3}{c}{December 31, 2019}\\
&& \\
@\multicolumn{1}{c}{\uppercase{Assets}} & @\multicolumn{1}{c}{2019} & @\multicolumn{1}{c}{2018}\\
@\multicolumn{1}{c}{Current Assets}&&\\
@ Cash & 12345 & 54321\\
@ Receivables:&&\\
@ \hspace{0.25in}Sewer Fees: & 12345 & 54321\\ \cline{2-3}
@\multicolumn{1}{r}{Total Current Assets}  & sum(b7:[0,-1]) & sum(c7:[0,-1])\\ % r10
@\multicolumn{1}{c}{\uppercase{Fixed Assets}}&&\\
@ Land & 12345 & 54321\\
@ Garage & 99247 & 54321\\
@ Equipment & 12345 & 54321\\
@ Lagoon and Related & 12345 & 54321\\ \cline{2-3}
@\multicolumn{1}{r}{Total Fixed Assets} & sum(b12:[0,-1]) & sum(c12:[0,-1])\\ \cline{2-3} % r15
@ Accumulated Depreciation & -12345 & -54321\\ \cline{2-3}
@\multicolumn{1}{r}{Net Fixed Assets} & sum(b16:[0,-1]) & sum(c16:[0,-1])\\ \cline{2-3}
@\multicolumn{1}{r}{Total Assets} & b18+b10 & c18+c10\\ \cline{2-3} \cline{2-3}
\end{spreadtab}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Where rather than `Accumulated Depreciation -12345 -54321`, it reads `Accumulated Depreciation (12345) (54321)`.

I have found scant little information about it online, and I'm not entirely certain it's possible to do.
If at all possible, I would like to retain the decimal alignment while adding the parentheses. But again, I'm not sure it's possible.

A solution, below, was shared on StackOverflow several years ago, but it concludes in several errors which I am unsure how to move beyond: primarily the compiler complaining about dozens of "missing" or "extra" brackets.

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\STprintnum[1]{\FPifneg{#1}(\@gobble#1)\else#1\fi}
\makeatother
```

Update: Per the below answer, using SIunitx permits wrapping negative numbers in brackets, but this breaks the decimal alignment. A minimum working example of this is as follows:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{spreadtab}
\sisetup{group-separator = {,}}
\sisetup{bracket-negative-numbers = true}

\begin{document}
\begin{spreadtab}{{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XS[table-format=7.1]S[table-format=7.1]}}
@ Fixed Assets & 123456.1 & 135791.1\\
@ {Accumulated Depreciation} &-100000.1 &-90000.1\\ \cline{2-3}
@\multicolumn{1}{r}{Net Fixed Assets} & sum(b1:[0,-1]) & sum(c1:[0,-1])\\ \cline{2-3}
\end{spreadtab}
\end{document}
```

In the above example, the negative numbers are now offset in their alignment by the left and right parenthesis, so they cease to line up with the positive numbers.

Comment: Have a look at the sunitx package. It has a build in option to bracket negative numbers

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I added this functionality in, and it works fairly well. The only issue now is that the alignment is skewed after including it. Bracketing the negative numbers in this way causes the alignment to cease matching with the alignment of positive numbers - it is skewed by the opening and closing parentheses.